# how to keep the text box size fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[My Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlG6bJcBP8jaxhVEZ4wq?p=preview)

In this plunker there is a double plus button. If I press double plus button, The text box is moving right. The text box right corner should be fixed for parent and child. It should be the right side size fixed like the first textbox. How can I achive that functionality.

**Update:-**  Expecting output like the below[image]

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></span></a>
              <input type="text" ng-model="item.rowId">
```

Comment: So it should not be adding a subtree to your parent row? What exactly is the expected behaviour?

Comment: when I press double plus then the textbox right side size should not increase than the parent row

Comment: it's child @Murali

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya yes it is child. For child only I need to achieve this functionality

Comment: that way it's right side control move

Comment: If you inspect the newly created, you will see that your code is adding an <ol> element.  By default it had some left padding which is what is causing the extra space.  I would think you would want this to be an <li> and be part of the same list, rather than a <ol>

Comment: please find my updated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to keep the text box size always static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925021/how-to-keep-the-text-box-size-always-static)

Answer (score 0):

there is one extra attributes is adding on li in your defined angularjs library:

```
.angular-ui-tree-nodes .angular-ui-tree-nodes {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

remove padding-left attribute from here, then you go the right one.

Answer (score 0):

The  element that is getting created on click of double plus icon has a left padding of 20 px because of this code in your file "angular-ui-tree.min.css" :

```
.angular-ui-tree-nodes{padding-left:20px}
```

Can you check this and let me know if this solves your problem?