# how to keep the text box size always static

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[My Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlG6bJcBP8jaxhVEZ4wq?p=preview)

In this plunker there is a double plus button. If I press double plus button, The text box is moving right. But it should not be like that. It should be the right side size should be fixed like the first textbox. How can I achive that functionality.

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></span></a>
              <input type="text" ng-model="item.rowId">
```

**Expecting output:-**

[image]

Comment: And you are using bootstrap?

Comment: @epascarello yes I am using bootstrap

Comment: have you tried giving it a full row?

Comment: I am not understanding what you want to achieve. your double plus button , depending upon which item is clicked is adding adidtional <ol><li>s  . Do you want everything to be in the same <ol> instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to keep the text box size fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923258/how-to-keep-the-text-box-size-fixed)

Answer (score 2):

if you right click on the elment that is wrong you can find the "inspect" entry within the context menu. (using chrome)

what you can see then is the class on the element that is not right:
in your case (if I got the question right)

```
.angular-ui-tree-nodes .angular-ui-tree-nodes {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

the entries have a padding.

this css specific code is within the "angular-ui-tree.min.css" file (minified css file)

*to make such a file readable you can use a css beautifier for example 
http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/ (first I've found hitting the search engine)*

to achieve the right result you can overwrite that css code within your own "demo.css" css file for example by adding that:

```
.angular-ui-tree-nodes .angular-ui-tree-nodes {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this CSS to the page to put the default CSS

```
.angular-ui-tree-nodes .angular-ui-tree-nodes {
    padding-left: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: If I add the above css then it is missing the parent and child relationship... I don't want to  loose that relationship..But If you find the image that I attached you can find my requirement

Comment: Css only change the appearance.

Answer (score 0):

See the Updated HERE ==> [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ANKkWoSvNs5cIvSeToTn?p=preview)

```
.angular-ui-tree-nodes{
   padding:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: it's missing the parent and child relationships

Comment: What you exactly want...?

Comment: Please find the image that I attached

Comment: That i see, so what's the problem with your plunker because it's working like as you want..

Do you want top-bottom space for child and parent row....?

Comment: In The image there is a parent and child relationship.. In our updated pluker given by you is not having the parent and child relationship.. and in the image that I attached formated right side in the textbox... It will not cross the right side.. But It will move to right for child

Answer (score 0):

```
.angular-ui-tree-nodes .angular-ui-tree-nodes {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```