# How to fix the text box size

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[My Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlG6bJcBP8jaxhVEZ4wq?p=preview)

In My plunker there is d `++` button. If I press on that button the child text box is moving right side, as it is functionality.It's fine. But when the child text box comes then the child text box is crossing the parent text box. I want to restrict the text box like the below.

Image:

[image]

Comment: There is no ++ in the plunker you have shared.Can you please update your plunker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to keep the text box size always static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925021/how-to-keep-the-text-box-size-always-static)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923258/how-to-keep-the-text-box-size-fixed